# Change the default number of last post on homepage to something other than 1

Tags: phpbb3

Out of the box, as far as I can tell, phpBB 3.1.10 displays one thread post per Category within a forum on the homepage, the "last post". Is there a way to change the default number of "last posts" displayed in a category? For example:

```
Pub
    Chit Chat
-------> Best Beer [**Only this one is displayed - "Last Post"**]
-------> Best Bike to ride to a bar
------->...
-------> Thread N
    Politics & Religion
--------> Trump [**Only this one is displayed - "Last Post"**]
--------> The Pope
--------> Thread N
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right: phpBB 3.1.10 displays one thread post per Category. And there is no configuration for that parameter. It's hard coded. Because of queries optimizations, phpbb team do an important choice : the last author, the last post and its links are duplicated in the `phpbb_forum` table. So to display the forum list and the last post, phpbb engine need only one request.

If you want to do that, you have to alter code retrieving these data and the [forum_list_body.html](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/forumlist_body.html). And I think you couldn't do it only with the extension system. You will have to alter core of the forum. The modification will alter performance, because you will have to launch a query for each category and each forum to retrieve the N last posts of each forum.